# I was being charged while on free dyno option on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

After being authenticated with a credit card, I was charged USD.96 on heroku. What exactly does this mean? Why am I getting charged when I use the free dyno type? Will I be charged every month .96$ to run my free dynos?

I thought it was free, but I'm now getting charged for it.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I configured a custom domain on a free dyno herocu charged me this .96 USD amount and it was one time.

Comment: Are you certain that I won't be charged every month for free dyno type? and it is only being charged once.

Comment: are you using any other services other than the dyno? otherwise, when you add your card to an account, it is cutomary to charge a 1 time fee (around 1 USD)

Comment: I'm not using any other services but What I had done in the past after I was charged with 1 USD I removed the card from Heroku for a safe side, and it's still working.